# 2 Signatures added to wse security

Tags: wcf, timestamp, token, saml, signature

I needed to signature in the wse security with SAML token similar to [Need signature after SAML token in client request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22951121/need-signature-after-saml-token-in-client-request) But when I followed the example I get signature for both the soap body and the timestamp. Where as the server where I send the request to need only the timestamp signature (error: Two references found in the signature for the timestamp. Expected one reference). I spent many hours searching in the google and tweaking the WCF settings but to no avail. Following is the signature with 2 references (to body and to the timestamp). Is there anything I can do before manually creating the wse header and its contents

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#_0">
<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>DFvTr5YpOqj58TjzI6gd6BNhETw=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
<Reference URI="#_1">
<Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>K05w1zXD270nLcMhwK6uPP+2qL4=</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo><SignatureValue>truncatedsignature</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference b:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV2.0" xmlns:b="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd"><o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLID">_9329f9d7-db5c-4971-940c-b2a4e400238e</o:KeyIdentifier></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature>
```

Comment: Do you have a policy for WCF?  Is <sp:Body/> in the SignedParts at the bottom?  If so, take it out.

Comment: I don't know specifically how WCF processes Security headers and if they enforce WS-Policy 1.2 and above, but in WS-Policy 1.2 and above, it says that if you have a Timestamp in the policy, it must go inbound and outbound and be integrity protected by either message-level security or SSL.  Some runtimes enforce that and some don't.  It is possible that, if you have both a signature and Timestamp in your policy, WCF is going to sign your Timestamp.